# How to transfer values on the same jsp in Jquery UI Tabs

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, jstl, el

How to transfer values on the same jsp in Jquery UI Tabs for tabs-2 receive value?

I use el receive sqlserver data.

After how to transfer value to tabs-2 in same jsp?

Thank a lot in advance.

```
    <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">商品列表</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">購物車</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="tabs-1">
      <table border="1">
    <c:forEach var="sss" items="${store}">
    <tr>
    <td>${sss.itemid}</td>
    <td>${sss.itemname}</td>
    <td>${sss.itemprice}</td>
    <td><button type="submit" value="${sss.itemid}">加入購物車</button>
    </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </table>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-2">
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What is desired output? Could you please rephrase the question.

Comment: @PrashantZombade I want to get the value of the button,take the database select table and then display it to the same page(tabs2)